# mongoose can't store double types?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to store double BSON type inside mongodb. I am using mongoose. I have tried every possible way but still it's stored as int.
I have tried @mongoosejs/double and mongoose-float but none of them work.

```
await Variant.insertOne(
    
    {
          price: 345,
          discount: 10,
     },
)
```

product model

```
import { Schema } from "mongoose"
const Double = require("@mongoosejs/double")

// const Float = require("mongoose-float").loadType(mongoose)
export const ProductVariantEmbeddedSchema = new Schema({
  price: Double,
  discount: Double,
})
```

here is a custom type that I have created by the help of @mongoosejs/double.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

export default function mongooseDouble(mongoose) {
  class DoubleType extends Number {
    constructor(v) {
      super(v)
      this.value = v
    }

    toBSON() {
      return this.value
    }
  }

  class Double extends mongoose.SchemaType {
    constructor(key, options) {
      super(key, options, "Double")

      Object.assign(this.$conditionalHandlers, {
        $lt: (val) => this.castForQuery(val),
        $lte: (val) => this.castForQuery(val),
        $gt: (val) => this.castForQuery(val),
        $gte: (val) => this.castForQuery(val),
      })
    }

    cast(val) {
      if (val == null) {
        return val
      }

      const _val = Number(val)
      if (isNaN(_val)) {
        throw new mongoose.SchemaType.CastError(
          "Double",
          val + " is not a valid double"
        )
      }
      return new DoubleType(_val)
    }
  }

  mongoose.Schema.Types.Double = Double
  mongoose.Types.Double = DoubleType

  return mongoose
}
```

// export default Double

Comment: Why do you say values are stored as ints?

Comment: @D.SM yeah if it's int stored as int and if it's decimal stored as double. but I want to store as double no matter if it's decimal or not

Comment: What evidence do you have that this isn't already happening?

Comment: db.Variant.find({price: {$type: "double"}})
return null
db.Variant.find({price: {$type: "int"}})
return values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it seems that if mongoose custom types not worked I can use raw mongodb queries.

```
import mongoose, {mongo} from 'mongoose'

const result = await mongoose.connection.collection('Variant').insertMany([{price: new mongo.Double(34)}, {price: new mongo.Double(45)}]) 

const storedValues = result.opt
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no such type as `Double`. JavaScript has `Number` which supports int, float, double, etc. Also, if you see mongoose documentation then you will see `Double` is not a valid type. Instead, you should use `Number`.

```
const ProductVariantEmbeddedSchema = new Schema({
  price: Number,
  discount: Number,
});
```

EDIT: After discussion in the comment I believe this can be a workaround.

```
const price = 5;
await Model.create({
    price: price * 1.0001,
    ...
});
```

In the database, the price would be a double type but the value would be `5.0005`. So, whenever you want the use the value of `price` either make it `int` or use `.toFixed(2)` or similar function to limit the decimal point to 2 places.

Comment: mongoose by itself don't have but we can use plugins to or create a custom one.
for e.g  @mongoosejs/double

Comment: I understand. But what is the purpose? In js you don't need to typecast. You can do arethmetic operation with  any number type regardless if its decimal values.

Comment: I am using prisma and mongoose together. the return type of prisma is float but the value stored is int and it throw an error. so I should store price as double

Comment: @Ehsansarshar I have updated my answer. This might not be a perfect solution but it should work.

Comment: a workaround. tnx. but it's still an issue and I hope that be fixed. because I have already added custom Type but don't know why not worked

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that works :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const setter = (value: any) => {
    const result = mongoose.Types.Decimal128.fromString(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));
    result._bsontype = 'Double'; // solution
    return result;
};

const Double = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        anyDoubleValue: {
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Mixed,
            set: setter
        }
    },
    {
        collection: 'double'
    }
);

export = mongoose.model('DoubleModel', Double);
```

You can manually change the _bsonType properties to `Double`